# how to solve ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when throwing exeption?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have implemented errorhandling:

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        var exception = ctx.Server.GetLastError();

        bool isAjaxCall = string.Equals("XMLHttpRequest", Context.Request.Headers["x-requested-with"], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        Context.ClearError();
        _log.Error("errorr occured, error:  " + exception.Message);

        if (isAjaxCall)
        {
            //Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            Context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            Context.Response.Write(
                new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
                    new { error = exception.Message }
                )
            );
        }

        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectToRoute("Error");
        }

    }
```

and testing it in a controller:

```
    // GET: Book
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("test");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw e;
        }

        return View("BooksMain");
    }
```

This should redirect me to my error controller

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    // GET: Error
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ErrorPage()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Error",
             url: "Error",
             defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "ErrorPage" }
        );
```

All i am getting is

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

in the browser

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have view with name ErrorPage may be an error occurs in the ErrorPage Method so it is looping through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url you have defined for "Error" is incorrect. try this :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Error",
    "Error/ErrorPage",
    new { controller = "Error", action = "ErrorPage" }
);
```

Comment: well this is worth laughing about... thank you, did the trick

Comment: What is wrong with the url Error is enough as he is giving default values for action